# using the mysqli_connect() for php

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I am writing code for PHP / MySQL for my website. I have it setup where

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("HOSTNAME","username","password","Database");
```

the content above is replaced. When I have it on my website is there any worry about Simultaneous users looking on my webiste, would that cause overload using the same variable over and over?

**For example:**

user 1 gets on page index.php using the `$connect = mysqli_connect();`

user 2 gets on page index.php using the same variable `$connect = mysqli_connect();`

user 1 and user 2 go at the same time to the same web page. would this cause an error? if so how to avoid this?

Comment: It is not. There are different theads, managing each request of users.

Comment: you are diving too dip into occean :)